# SOA service registry and dependency tooling

Tags: web-services, dependencies, soa

The company I work for is at the start of large project to transition a monolithic desktop application to a SOA architecture. Part of this project will require a service registry to be created.

I've seen fairly simple spreadsheets with details like service name, version, etc however I think we need more detail than this. Our architecture has a number of layers, each with some form of version depencenies. For example, external schemas -> canonical schemas -> .NET libraries.

This data could be used by developers for impact analysis, and also in upgrade/rollback deployment activities.

A custom service registry database is what comes to mind with 1-many dependencies for any given layer. For any given service/.NET library, we could then walk the tree to find the set of dependencies. Are there any tools recommended for this, or comments on this approach?

Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 0):

John this is a bit of opinion based question so it might start a flame war but hopefully not. I am in a very similar position as you and got myself a copy of the book SOA governance in Action by Jos Dirksen see [this](http://www.manning.com/dirksen/) link for more information.

The book deals primarily with open source tools so it might not be your cup of tea. However there are some great examples of how the entire SOA governance system should work. So I would suggest you read it if you can.

As far the registry is concerned I started using the WSO2 Governance Registry server which was detailed in the book. Go to [this](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/) link to download it and give it a spin. Easy to setup and get running and it seems to fit the bill for us. Once again your mileage might vary.